# include two PHP files in one html file is not working

Tags: php, html, css, php-include

I have two php files which are doing some database work so i want to show them on single page so i created an html file and include both of the php files, this methods work well every time i use but not working now, please help to solve. Both file works good if i open them individually very well but including them in one html file is not working, including single php file is not working either, i am using single css file for both of php file and i tried even without css but they do not appear in main html.

```
            <html>
            <body >
                        <? php include 'user_addf.php'; ?>
                        <? php include 'user_remf.php'; ?>          
            </body>
            </html>
```

PHP file User_addf:

```
                <link href="users_forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <div id="leftcolumn">
                    <form method="post" action="user_management_modf.php"><br/>
            <legend> Add Users </legend>
            <fieldset>
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="uname" id="" /><br /><br />
            Password :
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
                </div>


            <?php
                                // PHP code 
            ?>
```

---

2nd Php File user_remf:

```
                <link href="users_forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <div id="rightcolumn">
                    <form method="post" action="user_remv.php"><br/>
            <legend> Remove Users </legend>
            <fieldset><br/>

            <?php
                        include'connect.php';
                        $q=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user");

                        echo "<select name=uname_list''><option>Select a username</option>";
                        WHILE($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                         {
                            echo "<option name='uname_remove' value=$row[username]>".$row[username]."</option>"; 
                         }
                         echo "</select>";
            ?>

            <br/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete User" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What is the output your are getting ? Please make sure you save your main html file with an extension of php

Comment: I even tried to make the main file an php file but it still not working

Comment: white page, nothing appears !

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Do this at the top of your main php file

Comment: nothings shows, just white page...

Comment: Tell me, is `<? php` what you're actually using with the space? Plus, is the file you're running holding the `.php` extension? Also, running on local machine or hosted site?

Comment: Yes its like,  <? php...?> format and i am testing on xampp, first i go with "<? php include 'user_remf.php';  ?>" format in main.html file and then tried "include 'user_remf.php'; " in an main.php file

Comment: You mention *PHP file User_addf* but your file you say is user_addf.php - user_addf.php and User_addf.php are not considered the same on many systems.

Comment: No they are different, fist its like, <? php include 'user_addf.php'; ?> <? php include 'user_remf.php'; ?> in main.html and include 'user_addf.php';
include 'user_remf.php';   in main.php

Comment: You cannot have a space between `<?` and `php` it must be `<?php` together.

Comment: You're welcome. I prepared and posted an answer below which you can accept to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a space between `<?` and `php` it must be `<?php` together.

Modify your code so that it is like this:

```
<?php include 'user_addf.php'; ?>
<?php include 'user_remf.php'; ?>
```

Having error reporting set would have given a parse/syntax error similar to this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in...

I used an "echo" statement in a quick test just to show you a possible message.

```
<? php 
echo "Hello world";
```

Then in comments you stated:

> *No they are different, fist its like,   in main.html and include 'user_addf.php'; include 'user_remf.php'; in main.php*

You can only execute PHP in `.html` files if you instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Either you do that, or rename the extension to be `.php`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @Mahesh Thank you. I feel it's important to point out details as to why code fails. Without an explanation, no one will learn anything. *Cheers*

Comment: Yes I agreed with you. keep it up